# Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined' Vanilla JS - Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

I am learning redux and tried some code following a YouTube video. I created a simple **Vanilla JS App** and installed redux in it but when I run the app in the terminal I am getting "Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'"

**Below is my index.js file**

```
const redux = require("redux");
const legacy_createStore = redux.legacy_createStore();

const BUY_CAKE = "BUY_CAKE"; //define action type

//Action creator function that returns the action object
function buyCake() {
  //action object with type as type of action and some other info
  return {
    type: BUY_CAKE, //set action type
    info: "first redux action",
  };
}

//(prevState, action) => newState

const initialState = {
  numberOfCakes: 10,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_CAKE:
      return {
        //always return new state objet since a reducer is a pure function
        ...state, //state object might have other states as well so it is safer to copy those states first and change the required state
        numberOfCakes: state.numberOfCakes - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = legacy_createStore(reducer);
console.log("Initial state : ", store.getState());
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log("Update state : ", store.getState())
);
store.dispatch(buyCake());
store.dispatch(buyCake());
store.dispatch(buyCake());
store.dispatch(buyCake());
unsubscribe();
```

**Below is the error stack:**

```
Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'
    at Object.createStore (D:\Taha\YouTube\Redux\redux_demo\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:166:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Taha\YouTube\Redux\redux_demo\index.js:2:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

**Below is my Package.json **

```
{
  "name": "redux_demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "redux": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `const store = redux.legacy_createStore(reducer);`

Comment: I am already getting legacy_createStore() on the very second line.

Comment: But you're doing it wrong. Have you tried it with the code in my previous comment?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work at that time. But when I ran it today, it started working. Can you tell me how it was wrong the way I wrote it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

`const legacy_createStore = redux.legacy_createStore();`

Use like this:

```js
const redux = require('redux');

const store = redux.legacy_createStore(reducer);
```

Comment: OMG! It actually worked. Can u please tell me what was wrong with the way I wrote it? I mean I just followed through a video so I pretty much copy-pasted.